# Dynamic summing with two-way criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically I have a table like this:

[image]

The Names are filtered from another table and are dynamic.

I am trying to sum the values based on two criteria ("Duration" and "Day of week"), like this:

`=SUMIFS($B5:$E5,$B$2:$E$2,G$2,$B$3:$E$3,G$3)`

This gives a correct result, but I want the formula to dynamically update, based on the dynamic formula that contains the names. So I tried this:

`=IF(A5#<>0,SUMIFS($B5:$E5,$B$2:$E$2,G$2,$B$3:$E$3,G$3),0)`

This goes way down the table, but it always returns the sum of the first row.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this?

Comment: Change the sum_range in the sumifs(). It is correctly summing the first row as you told it to do.

Comment: @SolarMike I can try that, but how would that make the formula dynamic when there are other rows dynamically added to the table; the sumifs() wouldn't keep up with the change in that case.

Comment: Can you edit your screenshot to include row numbers and column headers - without them your formulae can't be related to your data ?

Comment: Surely the result is based on the criteria: duration & day of week?

Comment: @SpectralInstance I just did it, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @SolarMike yes but we have basically another dynamic criteria, which is the name of the person!

Comment: So add the third criterion, as you don't have it included yet.

Comment: @SolarMike I've tried that as well but it's returning a #value error for some reason. Maybe because it's two-way?

Comment: The absence of the name criterion makes it a bit fuzzy for me - am I correct in thinking that, as currently populated, you would like column G data to replicate column B data but that it would 'grow' dynamically as the number of names grows ?

Comment: Test with just the names - either you have the syntax wrong or the names don’t match ie typing error.

Comment: @SpectralInstance pretty much that's the point. Except G doesn't replicate B, but sums it up (there will be more columns in the real worksheet).

Comment: Ok, so the formula for G5 would be =SUM(INDEX($A$5#,,MATCH(G2&G3,$A$2:$E$2&$A$3:$E$3,0))), right?

Comment: @SpectralInstance this is giving me a #REF error. I also tried with one condition, same error.

Comment: I've added a reply so that I could include a screenshot, indicating that the formula does produce a valid result

Answer (score 0):

Just posting an answer so I can include a screenshot - illustrating that the formula

```
=SUM(INDEX($A$5#,,MATCH(G2&G3,$A$2:$E$2&$A$3:$E$3,0)))
```

*does* produce a valid result

[image: screenshot of proposed formula]

Comment: your formula still gives me a #REF error. I guess for lookup array you should have B2:E2&B3:E3 not A2:E2&A3:E3. Nevertheless, this doesn't produce a result, you can analyze the formula for yourself; what numbers did you sum, you have no reference to them. Also, your result number in this screenshot is wrong: we're looking for an "8" as a result (since Joshua worked 8 hours on Saturdays, not 24. Further, your formula doesn't fill the cells below, i.e. it is not a dynamic array formula for some reason.

Comment: I've made some research before posting this question, hoping to find a solution but this seems to be an interesting problem; I haven't seen anyone tackle it this way. I will try more and hopefully we'll get somewhere. Nevertheless, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: My formula sums a column of the dynamic array (a#), such column being result of the Match function, which identifies the combination Duration & 7 as being position 2 in the A2:E5 range, so the end result is a sum of the column B portion of a#.
In your penultimate comment of the question, you wrote that the formula was to sum up column B, and you didn't have ANY name criterion specified - perhaps if you EDITED your question, specifying ALL criteria and, for a given cell(s) specify what value(s) you expect then I can EDIT my answer accordingly.